# "Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link" - Why?

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with my code? I keep getting this error: `Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in functions.php on line 4
error reading database`

```
function gameTableCheck($gn) 

{

    $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$gn'",$db) or die ('error reading database'); //This is line 4
    if (mysql_num_rows ($result)>0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if( gameTableCheck($page) === false ) {
        echo "MAO";
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$db` is not a local variable inside function `gameTableCheck`, you need to add a `global $db;` statement at the top of the function.

Comment: or (better IMO) pass in $db as a parameter to the function

Comment: This is assuming of course that there is a `$db` in the global scope.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here: `mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$gn'",$db)`

There is no `$db` in scope.

If you are only using one database connection and you have already connected, you can just remove this argument.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd say that $db is not initialized correctly. What you want to do is to use `mysql_select_db` as such :

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //database location
$user = "user"; //database username
$pass = "pass"; //database password
$db_name = "thename"; //database name

//database connection
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

//sets encoding to utf8
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
?>
```

(snippet [via](http://www.novaksblog.com/2007/10/02/database-connection-with-php/))

If you do need to have a specified database variable on each query for some reason, try looking if :

- the $db variable is set properly
- the $db variable is within the scope of your function. [Consider making it global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) if needed or passing it to the function as an argument

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `$db` is not a valid database connection.
Did you connect to the database beforehand? Is `$db` available in that function's scope at all?

You can make it have global scope by using `global $db` before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open the connection to your database ($db in your code) and select a database before executing a query on it. The error says that the $db variable in your code is not a valid resource and thus it is not defined.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

to find the error you can try putting mysql_error()

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$gn'",$db) or exit( mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `gameTableCheck()` function has no clue what the `$db` variable is. Since PHP has no dynamic scoping you have to either declare the variable as `global` inside the function (if it is a global variable), or pass it as a parameter in the function call.